# OpenShift hostpath volumes and accented characters

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, volumes, mounted-volumes

I created a volume of type hostpath using this command :

```
oc volume deploymentConfig/airsonic-webapp --add --type=hostPath --path="/var/music" --mount-path="/mnt/DATA" --containers="airsonic-webapp"
```

The volume is effectively created and mounted on the *airsonic-webapp* container as */mnt/DATA*.

The problem is that all accented characters in that volume are ignored.

In the following snippet, I rsh to the *airsonic-webapp* pod and list files in the mounted volume. 
The file displayed as R??mi is in fact maned Rémi.

```
remi@REMI-DELL-XPS-15:/mnt/DATA/oc/adm$ oc rsh airsonic-webapp-6-j8khz
sh-4.2# ls /mnt/DATA/test  
R??mi 
sh-4.2#
```